# ember.js containerview view controller binding not working

Tags: ember.js

My Ember Code is not binding child's view to its controllers under ContainerView Controller

I have a template "metrics" for which MetricsView is not pulling title attribute value from its controller. This is a child view under container view and same is happenig with all other views which are under containerview.

Here is the code snippent I am using:

This is how my Container View looks like

```
// Container View
App.DashboardContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.create({
    childViews: [],
    view1: App.MetricsView,
    view2: App.ResultsView,
});
```

This is how my Child view looks like:
    App.MetricsView = Ember.View.create({
        template: Ember.TEMPLATES["metrics"]
    });

This is how my Child View's Container looks like:
    // Child View's Controller which is not binded with Child View,
    // Wanted to render title from this Controller to template

```
App.MetricsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    title: 'Metrics Page', // To Be deleted later
    content : []
    metrics : [],

    view: Ember.View.create({
      templateName: 'metrics'
    }),

    show : function(petId, onDone, onFail) {
        _get('/fetch_one', onDone, onFail);
    },
});
```

Child Template // Here {{title}} is not printing on UI but "-- Summary" prints

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="metrics">
    <div class='well well-large'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span9">
                    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
                    <h4> -- Summary</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                    <button {{action "toggle" }} class="close">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Some other supported code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    appName: 'Portal',
    debug: true,
    demomode: 1,
    version: '0.0.1'
});

App.Router.map (function () {
    this.resource('pets');
    this.resource('pet', {path: ':pet_id'}, function(){
        this.resource('dashboard');
        this.resource('list', function() {
            this.route('summary');
            this.route('results');
        });
    });
});

//ApplicationRoute
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(){
    },
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('pets');
    }
});


App.PetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Pet.find();
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render({ outlet: 'rightpane' });
    }
});


App.PetsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties : [ 'first_name' ],
    sortAscending : true
});

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(){
        var menuItems;
        if (App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews')) {
            App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').pushObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
            App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').pushObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view2);

            menuItems = this.controllerFor('petDashboardMenu').get('model');
            $(menuItems).each(function(index, menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.id == 1 || menuItem.id == 2) {
                    alert(menuItem);
                }
            }); //TODO: Make the menu buttons active for which view is added.
        }

        //this.controllerFor('pets').set('model', App.Preference.find({ name: "Dennis" }));
        this.controllerFor('petDashboardMenu').set('model', App.PetMenuItem.find());
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render({ outlet: 'rightpane' });
    }
});

App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    name: 'Dashboard'
});

App.PetDashboardMenuController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    toggleMenuItem: function(menuItem) {
        var link = $(event.srcElement);
        var childViews = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews');
        if (link.hasClass('active')) {
            link.removeClass('active');
            var present = false;
            switch (link.text()) {
                case 'Summary':
                    present = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').indexOf(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
                    break;
                case 'Results':
                    present = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').indexOf(App.DashboardContainerView.view2);
                    break;
                default:
                    present = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').indexOf(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
            }
            if(present >= 0) {
                // ToDo : For All Menu Items
                switch (link.text()) {
                    case 'Summary':
                        App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').removeObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
                        break;
                    case 'Results':
                        App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').removeObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').removeObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
                }
                App.log('Removed Summary : Removed : View Count : ' + App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').length);
            } else {
                App.log('Removed Summary : Already Not Present : View Count : ' + App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').length);
            }
        } else {
            link.addClass('active');
            var present = null;
            App.log('Link Text : "' + link.text() + '"');
            switch (link.text()) {
                case 'Summary':
                    present = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').indexOf(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
                    break;
                case 'Results':
                    present = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').indexOf(App.DashboardContainerView.view2);
                    break;
                default:
                    present = App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').indexOf(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
            }

            if(present >= 0) {
                App.log('Adding Summary : Already Present : View Count : ' + App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').length);
            } else {
                // ToDo : For All Menu Items
                switch (link.text()) {
                    case 'Summary':
                        App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').pushObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
                        break;
                    case 'Results':
                        App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').pushObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').pushObject(App.DashboardContainerView.view1);
                }
                App.log('Added Summary : View Count : ' + App.DashboardContainerView.get('childViews').length);
            }
        }
    }
});

App.log = function(message) {
    if(App.debug) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};
```

Any pointers would be appreciated?

Comment: Can you put this into a jsFiddle and point to exactly what's not working as you expect?

Answer (score 2):

I was having difficulty with this exact issue when I discovered that the functionality is deprecated. I got the following warning:

> Manipulating a Ember.ContainerView through its childViews property is
>   deprecated. Please use the ContainerView instance itself as an
>   Ember.MutableArray.

You'll need to use pushObject as the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html) states.