# An example of ContainerView required where childViews are binded with their respective controllers

Tags: ember.js

Basically I am using a ContainerView where I am rendering multple child views. I able to push/remove views in childView but unable to map any controller and route to have model binding and pull couple of variables which are declared in ContainerView

Details here:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2171

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by overriding controller property of View.

```
App.MetricsView = Ember.View.create({
     templateName: 'summary',
     loaded: true,
     controller: App.SummaryController.create(),
});
```

Comment: Hello Soman, I am facing same issue in my project. could you please provide some more details about the controller which you have used is the same controller which your main view has? 
Is it possible for you to share some example code?

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012389/ember-js-containerview-view-controller-binding-not-working